# How do I use polymer 1.0 paper-styles colors?

Tags: css, polymer

How can I set the background-color of a paper-toolbar to --paper-teal-500?

```
  <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">

  <style is="custom-style">
    paper-toolbar {
        background-color: paper-teal-500;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0;">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">

  <paper-toolbar>
    <div title>Tabara</div>
  </paper-toolbar>
```

Comment: what is your problem  ? Show an exemple of your code into codepen or plunkr to let us understand

Comment: It could be that you aren't actually assigning this style, because it needs to be .paper-toolbar or #paper-toolbar.

Comment: There is nothing specific to show, it is quite a general question. The point is that I am looking for a way to use the paper colors defined in paper-styles/colors.html They are defined like this: --paper-teal-500: #abc123, and I want to use only the name of the color.

Comment: I am assigning the style correctly. background-color: green; works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I managed to figure it out.

```
background-color: var(--paper-teal-500);
```

will do.
Hope it helps anyone in need!